# It is not authing right after registiration with laravel Auth class

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

Everything is ok unless authing in this code. That returns "false". This is my first try with this class I'm already beginner for laravel. I don't know that is really basic problem but I can not see the problem, that's why I ask this.

```
public function signupDone(){
            $rules = array(
                'username' => 'required|unique:users|min:5', // Minumum 5 Characters and Unique
                'password' => 'required|min:8', // Password must be 8 characters, at least
                'password2' => 'same:password', // Password2 must be same of password
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users' // Email must be an e-mail adress unique
            );

            $validation_result = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
            if($validation_result->fails()){
                return Redirect::to('signup')->withErrors($validation_result);
            }

            $user = new Users;
            $user->username = Input::get('username');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            if($user->save()){
                if(Auth::attempt(array("username"=>$user->username, "password"=>Input::get('password')))){
                    return Redirect::to('/');
                }
                else{
                    return "false";
                }
            }
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
/config/auth.php

```
<?php

return array(
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => 'Users',
    'table' => 'users',
    'reminder' => array(
        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',
        'table' => 'password_reminders',
        'expire' => 60,

    ),

);
```

And users table:
[image]

Users Model:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
class Users extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
}
```

Comment: I don't know what exactly the problem is, but instead of using `Auth::attempt` you can just do `Auth::login($user)` to "manually" log a user in

Comment: $user?? is that username or what?

Comment: No the `$user` object you already have ;) [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#manually)

Comment: @Docs thanks man. It still returns false though.

Comment: Docs is not my name but a link to the Laravel documentation ;) anyways, I should have mentioned that `Auth::login()` returns `void`. So just do the redirect anyways and see if it you are logged in.

Comment: The password column in your database is too short.  Try making it 60 instead.

Comment: @lukasgeiter ahh I see. Then How can i check if user logged in or not? if that returns void??

Comment: @lukasgeiter You can use `Auth::check()` which will return true or false to determine if they are logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user3158900 noticed correctly, your password column needs to be **60 characters long**, otherwise the hash will be truncated become useless.

Still there's no need to use `Auth::attempt` if you *know* the users credentials are valid (because he just created his account).

In such cases you can just use [`Auth::login`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#manually)

```
if($user->save()){
    Auth::login($user);
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

There's no need to check if the login worked because:

1. You are not validating credentials
2. If anything drastically goes wrong an exception will be thrown

If the user for some reason doesn't get logged in without error there's still your `auth` filter that will redirect to a login form (I suppose)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have to change the password field to 60 varchar. But I've just noticed that, Auth::attempt returns false if username and password ok.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password)))
{
    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
```

Comment: After you changed the password to 60 varchar, did you re-seed the database with proper passwords?

Comment: @user3158900 not yet?

Comment: The problem is when you had the password set to 50 in the database, Laravel was storing the password but the last 10 characters were getting cut off.  So now when you are trying to check an email and password, Laravel is comparing the password entered to the password in the database and seeing they don't match (because the database password was cut off) so it's returning false.  You will have to re-save the users with their passwords so the full 60 character password is saved to the database.